# Display "build" button on Github repo

Tags: php, github, travis-ci

I have noticed on a few Github repositories ([like this one](https://github.com/Payum/Payum#payum)) that you can have various images show on the main page of your repository.  The image that I would like to show up on my repo is called the "build" button.  The "build" button shows whether or not all your tests are passing or not.  I would like to have this feature on my repo to prove that my code is passing all the unit tests I've written.

Some extra info:

- I use Travis CI to run all my tests
- The image I'm after looks like this: [image: Build passing] (note the image I want displayed is in the red box I've highlighted)

Comment: What is it you need assistance with? Does Travis CI not have docs on how to do that?

Comment: Travis does have docs, http://about.travis-ci.org/docs/user/build-configuration/ But I can't seem to find "build passing" image on that page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's part of their README.md file, just take a look at the raw source code to see how to embed it... https://raw.github.com/Payum/Payum/master/README.md

Comment: A simple solution.  Thanks